# .Net Core: What's the best way to authenticate using an existing database

Tags: c#, database, authentication, .net-core

I would like to know how can I authenticate users (with a login form) if I already have information about my users in a table.

I heard about Identity, but i haven't found information to do it without modifying my database structure. The problem is I don't have permissions to change the structure.

So, is there any way to do it **without migrations**? I have only access to my user table.

I also heard about JWT, but i don't know how to pass the token to my razor page.

**UPDATE**

I'm using SSMS. My DB has two tables: products and users

I want to use Users table to authenticate, but I can't make migrations

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: you should also provide some information what information is contained in said table (with regards to auth)

Comment: You could use Identity, but you'd have to implement some of the interfaces in your own classes I believe. But without more info about how your DB structure looks it's difficult to give any concrete help.

Comment: @NicholasHunter I'm using SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: You should never store user passwords, in a table or anywhere else. You can use Windows authentication to control access to the database. User permissions on the database are controlled by the database administrator. Create a table keyed on user name to control access to specific application functionality. You can get the user name at run time from the environment variable USERNAME. No login form required.

Comment: @HéctorQuintero SSMS is a client tool, not a database. ASP.NET Core already provides authentication and secure database storage. The best option is to use the built-in mechanism.

Comment: @HéctorQuintero `I haven't found information to do it without modifying my database structure.` what does that mean? You *don't have* any credential tables right now, so you'll end up modifying your database no matter what you do.